# I don't understand the Perl Taint mode error message

Tags: perl, taint

I have some old Perl code I have been told is vulnerable to Cross site scripting attacks or SQL injection attacks.  I figured I'd turn on taint mode by changing the shebang from `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/local/bin/perl -T` and now I get this error message:

```
Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch at <big long path>/main.cgi line 26.
```

The code looks like this:

```
  1 #!/usr/local/bin/perl  -T
.
.
.
 12 use strict;
 13
 14 use vars qw( %opt $VERSION );
 15
 16 use CGI qw/:standard *table start_ul/;
 17 use CGI qw(:debug);
 18 use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );
 19 #use CGI::Pretty qw( :html3 );
 20 $CGI::Pretty::INDENT = "    ";
 21 use Tie::IxHash;
 22 use FindBin qw($Bin); 
 23 use lib "$Bin/../../lib";
 24 use lib "$Bin/../lib";
 25
 26 use Common::Config;
```

The Common::Config is has this ownership and permissions:

```
$ ls -l lib/Common/Config.pm
-r--r--r--. 1 someguy example 5840 Oct  9 20:08 lib/Common/Config.pm
```

I tried changing the ownership to `apache` but I still get the taint error message.

UPDATE:

I have tried to untaint my `$Bin` variable like so:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);           # Where are we ?
if ($Bin =~ /^([-\@\w.]+)$/) {
        $Bin = $1;                      # $data now untainted
} else {
        die "Bad data in '$Bin'";       # log this somewhere
}
```

But I still get the taint error about `use Common::Config;`

Comment: I will update the question to include those lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `use lib` statement where an insecure variable is added to the include path?

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html

> Note that if a tainted string is added to `@INC`, the following problem will be reported:
>
> ```
> Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch
> ```

Comment: I do have `use lib`. What do I have to do? Just commenting out that line would cause problems.

Comment: @RedCricket it's probably the FindBin. You have to untaint `$Bin`.

Comment: I guess I do not understand how to untaint $Bin. I have updated by question can you please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?